# CSS "background-image" property won't display the image

Tags: html, css

I'm woriking on a site, and trying to make a sidebar in which I put my image before some text in

```
<a> </a> tags
```

I've made a new empty project to test if I messed up something in my previous one, but no Even in a new empty one background image won't show itself
here is the code:

```
<a href='#' title='Građevinski radovi'><span style="background-image: url('./Ikonice/GRADJEVINA.svg')"></span><span class='Title'>Gradjevinski radovi</span></a>
```

I am working in VS CODE and using "Live Server" extension, saw somewhere on here that might cause a problem, so I opened html noramally without live server, still no luck.

[Image of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL12m.png)

WHAT I TRIED:

I tried putting two dots ".." before the first "/, also tried putting the image in the same folder as "index.html", and not in the "ikonice" folder, but it won't work. Also tried changing

```
backgroung-image: url 

to

background: url
```

Comment: Span doesn't have a height width to show the background image try to set the span height width

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a span has no size by itself. It grows to its content's size. In your example, there is no content so the span will be of 0px width.

Here's a display of the problem, using just background color but the same is valid for images. I put two divs, one red and one blue, we can only see the blue one since it has text in it.

```html
<span style="background:red;"></span>

<span style="background:lightblue;">Test</span>
```

If you do not want to put text inside, you'll have to give it a width and a height. But since a span is meant to display inline, you'll need to change that too with `display:inline-block` or `display:block`

Comment: Nope, I tired still wont work
I added `Height, text, display:block` And image won't display
tho if I put `background-color` instead of image, the color is displayed

I also tried putting `<div></div>` instead of  `<span></span>` but it wont work

Comment: Then it is certainly due to a bad path to your image, did you check the browser's network tab in the developper console? You'll be able to see if it at least tries loading the image and if yes, you'll see the path it tries with the error if any.

Comment: I did again what you said and it works, looks like it just freaked out and didn't find the path to the image, It's the same as before, tho it works this time, Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**span with text**
it shows background image

```html
<a href="#"> 
     <span style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/300/200.jpg')">LOREMLOREM</span>
     <span class='Title'>Gradjevinski radovi</span>
</a>
```

**span without text**
it shows nothing since the `span` itself has no size

```html
 <a href="#"> 
   <span style="background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/300/200.jpg')"></span>
   <span class='Title'>Gradjevinski radovi</span>
</a>
```

so add some text in your `span` with `background-image`